# How to Change object property in params JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, param

Example:
I need create function like object, if i have simple object, i can get it like this:

```
myObject = function(){
   alert('tada');
}
```

but i need to implement this function or other param inner object like this:

```
myObject = {
   value : function(){
      alert('tada!');
   }
};
```

and call this function only by `myObject()`, not `myObject.value()`, thx

Comment: jQuery is a good example of a function that has methods, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: If there are more multiple params like `value`, how do you plan to call those ? I mean `myObject()` would rather work as constructor. What about accessing say `some_other_value_func` ?

Comment: you can also look into Object.defineProperty(myObject, "valueOf", {value: fn})

Comment: problem was in my bad js knowledge, if i write myObject = { param1: function(){tada!!}}, and later myObject = 'anyParam', myObject will be get 'anyParam', and myObject.param1() will be return 'tada', strange but js not replace object, when i assignment it later. i never seen this practice before in other languages

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass = function(){
  return {
   value : function(){
      alert('tada!');
   }
  }
});

instance = MyClass();
instance.value();
```

or more appropriately

```
// Define a class like this
function MyClass(name){
    this.name = name;
}

MyClass.prototype.sayHi = function(){
 alert("hi " + this.name);
}

var instance = new MyClass("mike");
instance.sayHi();
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects in JavaScript, so you can add properties onto a function. This is okay:

```
var obj = function() {
    alert("Hello, world");
}
obj.val = "42";
obj() //alerts "hello, world"
```

Comment: i need to use hash array construction in object, obj.param work, but i need other solution, thx

Answer (score 0):

```
obj = {
   myFunc: function(){
      alert('tada');
   }
};
obj = obj.myFunc();
```

this work for me!

Comment: Try calling it a second time…

Answer (score 0):

```js
myObject = (function() {
  return {
    value: function() {
      alert('tada!');
    }
    `enter code here`
  }
})();

myObject.value();
```